# Sleeker way to get $n>\delta\to\epsilon>|s_n-L|$ from $\inf\{|s_n|\}+\epsilon >|s_n| \geq \inf\{|s_n|\}$ and $|s_n| > |s_{n + 1}|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is covered by the theorem that bounded monotone sequences converge, but for exercise I'm trying to see if it can be proven for a specific type of monotone sequence without using this theorem and without separating the positive and negative cases.

I have a monotonic sequence  $\{s_n\}$ with both an infimum and a supremum and with $\forall n: |s_n| > |s_{n+1}|$. We notice immediately that the sequence doesn't cross $0$ but tends towards it, that it might be bounded before touching $0$, and that since $\epsilon + \inf\{|s_n|\}$ is not an infimum for $\{|s_n|\}$, there exists an $|s_\delta|$ s.t. $\epsilon + \inf\{|s_n|\} > |s_\delta| \geq \inf\{|s_n|\}$. Although doing the positive and negative cases individually is a breeze (note: in the negative case we use the supremum), is there a way to complete the argument that this sequence convergences, without using the theorem that a bounded monotonic sequence converges, and without doing the positive and negative cases individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let me take the symbol $N$ instead of $\delta$ and first write that:

$\inf|a_n|\le |a_N|\lt \inf|a_n|+\epsilon $

Let $\inf|a_n|=l$. Now note that for any $n\gt N$ we'll have $|a_n|\lt |a_N| $ whence

$l\le |a_n| \lt |a_N|\lt l+\epsilon\implies 0\le |a_n|-l\lt \epsilon$

and hence by definition of limit, $|a_n|\to l$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Do you know if $|a_n| - L < \epsilon$ is also an acceptable definition of a limit, or is it somehow derived from $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @shintuku: You're welcome. Please note that in this case: $||a_n|-l|=a_n-l$ and this is because $|a_n|-l$ is non negative. Also, note that $l$ is the infimum of the sequence $(|a_n|)$.

Comment: thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proof using Koro's comments:

Let $\{a_n \}$ be a monotonic sequence with $|a_n| > |a_{n+1}|$ with both an infimum and a supremum. Since $\inf|a_n| + \epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $|a_n|$, there exists an $N$ s.t. $n > N$.
$$\inf\{|a_n|\} + \epsilon > |a_N| \geq \inf \{|a_n|\}$$
$$\epsilon > |a_n| - \inf \{|a_n|\} \geq 0$$
Let $L = \inf \{|a_n|\}$. Then:
$$\epsilon > | |a_n| - L | = | -|a_n| - (-L)|$$
$\therefore \exists \mathcal{L} = (L \lor -L)$ s.t. $a_n \rightarrow \mathcal{L}$